# Priority of static functions in C

Tags: c, function, static, linkage

Let's say that you have a file File1.c with a static function Foo and that the function is called within File1.c. Also, in another file (File2.c), you have another Foo function which is not static. I understand that the static function is not visible outside of the file where it is declared and is actually invisible for the linker.

But does that mean that internal calling of Foo function in File1.c is always resolved during compilation?

Are there cases where Foo calling in File1.c can be linked to the global Foo function of File2.c?

Comment: short answers : "yes" for first question, "no" for the second

Comment: Check this out for an insight in static for the C language:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-static-functions-in-c/

Comment: @bruno, I don't think that's correct, static functions can still resolved by the linker (unless inlined), they are just flagged differently in the symbol table.

Comment: I think static symbols are not visible to the linker. I could be wrong.

Comment: @Frank the linker does not consider the static symbols, it bypasses them, even they can be visible for debug purpose

Comment: C standard states: "If the declaration of a file scope identifier for an object or a function contains the storageclass
specifier static, the identifier has internal linkage.22)"

Comment: For the second question, if `Foo` appears with both internal and external linkage within the same translation unit (the .c file plus its `#include`s) the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @IanAbbott the question scenario is Foo having internal linkage in one unit and external in the other unit,  not necessarily both at once

Comment: @M.M I was specifically addressing the second question: "Are there cases where Foo calling in File1.c can be linked to the global Foo function of File2.c?" N.B. File1.c already contains an internally linked Foo function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> does that mean that internal calling of Foo function in File1.c is always resolved during compilation?

Not necessarily. For the most part, the language itself does not care HOW its rules are enforced, just that they are enforced in the first place.

We can check how a given toolchain (in my case linux/gcc) chooses to do it with a quick test:

Starting from a a simple file (test.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void foo() {
    printf("hello");
}

void bar() {
    foo();
}
```

And then compile and inspect the resulting object file:

```
gcc -c -o test.o test.cpp
nm test.o

0000000000000018 T bar
0000000000000000 t foo
                 U _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 U printf
```

We see that both `foo()` and `bar()` are in the symbol table, but with different flags.

We can also look at the assembly:

```
objdump -d test.o

0000000000000018 <bar>:
  18:   55                      push   %rbp
  19:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  1c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  21:   e8 da ff ff ff          callq  0 <foo>
  26:   90                      nop
  27:   5d                      pop    %rbp
  28:   c3                      retq
```

And see that the call to foo is yet unlinked (pointing to the 0 placeholder). So we can say with confidence that the resolving can and does happen at link time in this instance.

> Are there cases where Foo calling in File1.c can be linked to the global Foo function of File2.c?

That's a straight no. It might be possible to make that happen through hacky magic or undefined behavior, but in a normal project, you should be confident it never happens.

Comment: The Linux/Unix command _nm_ shows easily the differences, _T_ for _bar_, _t_ for _foo_ (and _U_ for _printf_), may be add that in your answer ?

Comment: @bruno Thanks for the suggestion, it's indeed nicer this way.

Answer (score 6):

### Summary

Once you define a static function `foo` within a translation unit, `foo` refers to that function for the rest of the translation unit, except that it can be hidden by a non-function (such as an object or type definition) named `foo` for part of the translation unit. It will not link to an external function named `foo`.

By tinkering with declarations as explained below, an identifier **could** in theory refer to a function from another translation unit after a `static` declaration of the same name in this translation unit. Unfortunately, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, due to C 2018 6.2.2 7:

> If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

That means you cannot rely on the C standard alone to ensure this behavior, but a C implementation could define it as an extension.

### Details

These questions are answered by C’s rules for scope and linkage.

Suppose in `File1.c` we have a static definition of a function:

```
static int foo(int x) { return x*x; }
```

Since the identifier `foo` is declared outside of any function, it has file scope (C 2018 6.2.1 4). This means the identifier `foo` is visible and designates this function definition for the remainder of `File1.c`. Also, since `static` was used, it has internal linkage (6.2.2 3).

There is an exception to the scope. For scopes inside other scopes, such as the block `{ … }` that defines a function inside a file or a block inside a block, a declaration of the same identifier can hide the outer declaration. So let’s consider redeclaring `foo` inside a block.

In order to refer to a `foo` defined outside of `File1.c`, we would need to declare `foo` with external linkage, so that this new `foo` can be linked to the externally defined `foo`. Is there a way to do that in C?

If we try to declare `extern int foo(int x);` inside a block, then 6.2.2 4 applies:

> For an identifier declared with the storage-class specifier `extern` in a scope in which a prior declaration of that identifier is visible, if the prior declaration specifies internal or external linkage, the linkage of the identifier at the later declaration is the same as the linkage specified at the prior declaration.

So this declaration would merely redeclare the same `foo`.

If we declare it without `extern`, using `int foo(int x);`, 6.2.2 5 applies:

> If the declaration of an identifier for a function has no storage-class specifier, its linkage is determined exactly as if it were declared with the storage-class specifier `extern`.

So, it seems like we cannot declare a different foo with or without `extern`. But, wait, we have one more trick. We can make the prior declaration that specifies internal or external linkage invisible by hiding it with a declaration with no linkage. To get a declaration with no linkage, we can declare an object (rather than a function) without `extern`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int foo(int x) { return x*x; }

void bar(void)
{
    int foo; // Not used except to hide the function foo.
    {
        extern int foo(int x);
        printf("%d\n", foo(3));
    }
}
```

Since, where `extern int foo(int x);` appears, the prior declaration of `foo` with internal linkage is not visible, that first condition in 6.2.2 4 quoted above does not apply, and the remainder of 6.2.2 4 does:

> If no prior declaration is visible, or if the prior declaration specifies no linkage, then the identifier has external linkage.

This is “legal” C code. Unfortunately, it is undefined by 6.2.2 7:

> If, within a translation unit, the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Excellent answer! The only suggestion I have is to quote the remainder of 6.2.2p4 after the point where you say 6.2.2 4 does not apply.

Comment: OP's scenario doesn't necessarily include the situation "the same identifier appears with both internal and external linkage". (But he does ask "are there cases", so your scenario would be a case)

Comment: @M.M: How else could you have a static function `Foo` in File1.c and “Are there cases where Foo calling in File1.c can be linked to the global Foo function of File2.c?” The static `Foo` has internal linkage, and the call to the other `Foo` must have external linkage, so you have `Foo` with both internal and external linkage.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I don't think OP is suggesting intentionally trying to call File2.c's `foo` from File1.  But the question would have been clearer with a code example

Answer (score 0):

Here's a concrete example:

```
// a1.c
static void foo(void) { }
void bar(void) { foo(); }
```

and

```
// a2.c
void bar(void);
void foo(void) { bar(); }
int main(void) { foo(); }
```

In this example the code is correct:

- `a1.c` has the identifier `foo` declared with internal linkage and one matching definition.
- `a2.c` has the identifier `foo` declared with external linkage and one matching definition.

---

The area you would run into problems is if you attempt to have `a1.c` include a declaration for a2's `foo`.

For example: let's say `a2.h` has content `void foo(void);`,  and `a1.c` starts with `#include "a2.h"`. Here there is likely to be a compilation error, however the other answers show how there can be silent undefined behaviour through the use of evil constructs like block-scope function declarations.

It's also possible to have well-defined but unintended behaviour. If `a1.c` does `#include "a2.h"`  *after* `static void foo(void);` then there is no error, because there is a rule that a function declaration with neither `static` nor `extern` matches the linkage of earlier declaration of the same identifier if one exists; but in that case calling `foo()` from `a1.c` still finds a1's `foo`.   If `a2.h` also had a macro that called `foo()` then the macro would not behave as intended.